# dotnet in Ubuntu: Unable to resolve 'package_name' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'

Tags: nuget, ubuntu-14.04, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

I have a dotnet core project with packages from my private nuget source.

`dotnet restore` on a windows machine works fine.

Same operation on Ubuntu machine fails with an error
`Unable to resolve 'my package name' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.`, where `my package name` is a package from my private nuget repo

In `Feeds used:` section of output I can see my nuget source.

Nuget feed is avaible through `wget`.

I've tried different options of `dotnet restore` on both machines with same result.

How to diagnose this? Can it be a bug in sdk?

The only difference I can see is: `dotnet --version` on Windows is `1.0.3` while on Ubuntu is `1.0.1` (latest which can be installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works after: `sudo apt-get update`.